# Display information from JText in one class to DefaultTable in another

Tags: java

Why i can't retrieve the information using get Methods(from JText in one class) and display it in Default Table in another.

Please have a look at my code: http://pastebin.com/cEJ4dyqA

if(event.getSource() == new1)
         {

```
        for (int i = 0; i < db1.getMovies().size(); i++) {
                Movie movie = db1.getMovies().get(i);
        {
            String data1 = RunMovie.getTitle();
            System.out.println("Say:" + RunMovie.getTitle());
            String data2 = RunMovie.getActor();
            String data3 = RunMovie.getDirector();


           Object[] row = {data1, data2,data3};

           DefaultTableModel model1 = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();

            model.addRow(row);

        }
     }
```

Comment: Please post the relevant part of your code directly here, in your post.

Answer (score 0):

It is because in `RunMovie` you declare and initialize 3 `JTextFields`:

```
static  JTextField titlet = new JTextField(10);
static  JTextField actort = new JTextField(10);
static  JTextField directort = new JTextField(10);
```

and then you create another fields as local method variables:

```
JTextField titlet = new JTextField(10);
JTextField actort = new JTextField(10);
JTextField directort = new JTextField(10);
```

You create two separate sets of objects. In an effect, your methods `getTitle()`, `getActor()` and `getDirector()` get data from class fields, but you input data to local JTextFields, so you always get empty string. You should declare all your `JTextFields` in RunMovie (for example) like this:

```
static  JTextField titlet;
```

and in method initialize it this way:

```
titlet = new JTextField(10);
```

However, to add position to your Table you need to use `Save` button from main GUI(`textarea test`), not form additional `MovieDatabase` frame. I think it is bas idea, you should replace a `Save` button in `MovieDatabase` frame with Add button, which add movie to database, a then if user want, he could use save for saving whole Table with movies.